# Force variable expansion in GNU Make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How do I force GNU Make variables to evaluate immediately? Consider the following example:

```
TARGET:=fred
wilma:
    mkdir -p $(TARGET)
TARGET:=barney
betty:
    mkdir -p $(TARGET)
all: one two
.PHONY: one two all
```

With `make all`, Make will only create "barney", because the recipe strings are evaluated only after the makefile was read and the final value ("barney") was assigned.

I need to create both "fred" and "barney" in this instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
wilma: TARGET:=fred
betty: TARGET:=barney
wilma betty:
     mkdir -p $(TARGET)
```